# ankhsvn with Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2015, ankhsvn

Has anyone had any success using the new Visual Studio Community 2015 with the AnkhSVN subversion client?

All the components (VisualSVN server, TortoiseSVN, and AnkhSVN) are up to date and on the latest version, but attempting to access our Subversion server via AnkhSVN shows the message 'Error running context'. The Annkh forum on CollabNet hasn't any recent references, but an old thread suggests this might be a versioning issue with the new version of VS.

Any suggestions or successes, or will I need to wait for the various components to update to work properly with VS2015?

Comment: Why -2 votes? Should this be in another forum?

Comment: don't you get the same error in command-line client or TortoiseSVN? What's the complete wording of the error? `Error running context` has to be only the first part of the error.

Comment: Hi bahrep - TortoiseSVN seems to be fine - I've just done a diff on a couple of files and it seems to be working well, no error messages. <Error running context> occurs in the AnkhSVN 'Choose Repository' dialog, and that is the complete wording of the error I'm afraid.

Comment: I guess that then it makes sense to ask at AnkhSVN's mailing list https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=582

Comment: Fair enough, I'll try there. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 26):

You need to change the current source control plug-in to AnkhSVN.

Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Current source control plug-in

Comment: That has been set and is a fundamental requirement to use ankhSVN in Visual Studio. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Would be nice if the installer of AnkhSVN would make this change for you, or at least ask you whether it should make this change.

Comment: @gogognome Or at least mention that clearly on the download page.